# Some questions about splitting of sequence $0\to I\to\mathrm{Gal}_K\to\mathrm{Gal}_k\to 0$ for Henselian val field $K$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, local-fields

I have a couple of questions about [following proof](https://mathoverflow.net/q/386147) by Peter Scholze on splitting of the ses (...does it have a name?...)

$$0\to I\to\mathrm{Gal}_K\to\mathrm{Gal}_k\to 0$$

for $K$ henselian valuation field with residue field $k$, and the kernel $I$ is the inertia group.

Two steps are not clear for me:

**(1):** Why at the beginning $K$  can wlog be replaced by any algebraic extension $K'$ whose residue field $k'$ is purely inseparable over $k$?

**(2):** In the last part, if it is assumed that $K$ is replaced now by "maximal" extension $K'$ in since of *(1)*, with property not admitting nontrivial extenions of kind at in *(1)*, ie being in this sense *maximal*, why - if $I$ whould be nonzero and therefore there exist a map $I\to \overline{I}$ where $\overline{I}$ is a nonzero $\mathbb F_p$-vector space - the assumed maximality of $K$ would in turn neccessarily imply, that the induced sequence

$$0\to \overline{I}\to \overline{G}\to \mathrm{Gal}_k\to 0$$

is nonsplit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Since $k/k'$ is totally inseparable, the natural map $\mathrm{Gal}(k') \to \mathrm{Gal}(k)$ is an isomorphism, so if we have a splitting  $\mathrm{Gal}(k') \to \mathrm{Gal}(K')$, the composition

$$\mathrm{Gal}(k)\to \mathrm{Gal}(k') \to \mathrm{Gal}(K')\to  \mathrm{Gal}(K)$$
gives a splitting $\mathrm{Gal}(k)\to \mathrm{Gal}(K)$.

(2) $\overline{G}$ is a quotient of $\mathrm{Gal}(K)$ so quotients of $G$ give extensions of $K$. The splitting renders $\overline{I}$ a (nontrivial) quotient of $G$. The corresponding extension of $K$ has a residue field $k'$. If that were separable, then the action of $\overline{I}$ on a separable extension of the residue field would be nontrivial, contradicting that exact sequence.